# Flow of execution in Python

Tags: python

I'm completely new to Python and thus a bit confused about the flow of a program in Python.
If my understanding is correct, for a single `.py` file, if we add the line

```
if __name__ =="__main__": main()
```

The interpreter finds the main function and starts executing from there.
This, since Python execution goes sequentially line after line.

My question is if there are multiple `.py` files and 1 such file has the main function, like Java/C++ is there a way the python interpreter can know ad start executing the main function?

Comment: `__name__ == "main"` will only evaluate to `True` if you explicitly ran the .py file it's contained in. If it was imported, it will be `False`.

Answer (score 5):

The Python interpreter knows *nothing* of a `main()` function - the flow is just line by line.

The block that goes:

```
if __name__ =="__main__": main()
```

is a explicit call to a function if the magic variable `__name__` contains the string `"__main__"`. That thing, the content of `__name__` is the one special thing the Python runtime does when running a module: if the current module is the main program that was invoked, it contains the string `__main__`, otherwise its contents are rather the module name.

So, if you want your `main` function (which can have whatever name) placed in another file, you can just import it at invocation time:

```
if __name__ =="__main__": 
     from other_module import main 
     main()
```

This feature is interesting as it allows any Python file to work both as a loadable library module by other programs, and offer standalone functionality as a program.

However, for a Python package, that is, a folder containing related `.py` files, that each correspond to a module, Python has to choose which of these modules is run sequentially. When you execute a package using the `-m` directive to the Python runtime, it findes a file named `__main__.py` inside the package and executes that one - in the absence of such a file, the package cannot be run directly.

Follwing the same line of though, the `__main__.py` file is only run automatically when executing the package as the main program - if the package, or parts of it, are imported by another program, it is not executed. 
That, unlike checking the contents of `__name__` with an `if` expression is actually a built-in behavior that defines a starting-place.

Answer (score 2):

When you run a single Python script from the command-line with `python script.py`, interpretation starts at the first line and continues line by line. If a line starts a class or function definition, the definition is stored for later reference. If the line is executable code, it is directly executed. In the case of the statement `if __name__ == "__main__": main()`, this is directly executable, if the condition evaluates to true then `main()` is called. However, this isn't special. You can have whatever code you wish in the `if` body.